# "Dream of" and "dream about". Is there a difference?

Tags: word-difference

Are "dream of" and "dream about" interchangeable or is there a difference between them in meaning and usage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To dream **of** something implies a want, a need, a desire:

> I dream of traveling the world
>
> I dream of world peace
>
> I dream of Jeannie

To dream **about** something is to literally dream about something, and it's usually presented in the past tense:

> I dreamt about winning the lottery
>
> I dreamt about flying
>
> I dreamt about being a millionaire

To use it in the present tense is more common.

> I dream about becoming rich
>
> I dream about Jeannie
>
> I dream about wonderful things.

---

*To dream of* uses a different past tense form as well.

> DREAMED
>
> I dreamed of having the perfect house
>
> I dreamed of winning the lottery
>
> I dreamed of paradise on the beach.

These have nothing to do with dreaming while asleep.
They are all imagined, hoped for, **dreamed of**...

Comment: The part about dreaming while asleep ought to be addressed. I think _about_ would be the more natural prepostion, at least when _dream_ is used as a noun: _"Last night, I had a dream about eating a [giant marshmallow](http://thinkexist.com/quotation/i_had_a_dream_last_night-i_was_eating_a_ten_pound/339530.html)..."_

Comment: To me, "dreamed about" is just as natural/common/prevalent/apt to be heard/apt to be taught, at least in some places, as "dreamed of." In other words, I'm not sure about signalling out "dreamed" for "of" only.

Comment: Please don't use backticks (```) for emphasis or highlights. `Code formatting` makes text `very` difficult `and annoying` to `read`. Please use *italics* or **bold** instead.

Comment: I was startled to read that *dreamt of* was singled out as having a different past tense form *(dreamed of),* because to me *dreamed about* is a common past tense form of *dream about.*

Answer (score 1):

To speak about/of or think about/of doesn't normally have the two meanings that dream has. Dreams mean both a purely psychological phenomenon (at one end of its meaning), but can also mean a desire (as in my dream job, dream home, dream girl/boy, etc.

I suggest "Dream of" because it sounds more polite and romantic.

If I say "Dream about you" that covers the wide range of your dream, you could be flying or may get in a wonderland. While saying "Dream of you" that means being real.

Look at this example: I dream *of* becoming the US marine. (Internal Desire). Here you want something out from you.

I dream about a house/super car (External desire). Here you want to get something from an outside World.

Answer (score 1):

***To dream of is more specific***

> I dreamed of getting eaten up and going down a digestive system.

***To dream about is kind of the main idea of it***

> I dreamed about getting eaten up.

But from Spanish they both mean the same thing and Spanish is very old and basically knows best, so it can be both.